# Frattini subgroups and nilpotent groups: bijection?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, nilpotence

I have been proved that the Frattini subgroup of a finite group is nilpotent. Now I am wondering: is the converse true? I mean, if $G$ is a finite nilpotent group, is there always a finite group $H:\operatorname{Frat}(H)\cong G$?